# What happened if compute node restarts or stop working?

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

I wonder what is happening when a machine that runs computation node with active VMs is shutdown due hardware malfunction or power outage. After some time restarting and returns back? Does OpenStack somehow manage "to move" VMs that were configured to that node to run on another node? What happened to networking between VMs on other nodes trying to reach VMs that were running on the shutdown node?

Answer (score 0):

> Does OpenStack somehow manage "to move" VMs that were configured to that node to run on another node?

Not automatically.

If your OpenStack infrastructure has been configured with a common storage system for the compute nodes, then an instance that was running on the failed node can be migrated to another node and then booted.

> What happened to networking between VMs on other nodes trying to reach VMs that were running on the shutdown node?

Once the instance from the failed node has been restarted on a new node, other VMs will be able to talk to it ... using the instance's IP address.

Of course, network connections won't survive the failure.  (If a compute node fails, that brings down all instances that were running on it ...)

Comment: It is automatically possible with OpenStack. Please have a look at the Masakari project: https://github.com/openstack/masakari

Comment: Yea ... but that only applies if you have deployed Maskakari, and configured the instances to be HA.  Neither of those is "normal".